# Add extra field on check out page of Drupal 7

Tags: 7, commerce

All we want is for the customer to have to tell us how they heard about us at checkout page even when they did not make an account.

How do I add this extra field?

We are running Drupal 7 and below are the new modules installed to accomplish this new task:

- addressfield-7.x-1.0-beta2.zip
- commerce-7.x-1.0.zip
- commerce_extra_panes-7.x-1.x-dev.zip
- commerce_fieldgroup_panes-7.x-1.0-rc2.zip
- field_group-7.x-1.1.zip

Comment: Is this a question or a intention of doing a how-to?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can add a new field for your orders in "Store > Configuration > Order Settings > Manage Fields."

Next, using the [Commerce FieldGroup Panes](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_fieldgroup_panes) module, you can add the new field as a pane in your checkout.